# Calculated column issues

Tags: calculated-column

I created a calculated column in my SharePoint list and everything works fine until I add more than 20 lookup items.  Is possible to create a work around to correct this issue?  My formulas that work fine are below:

```
IF([Sample Type]="APP(EM)","4",
  IF([Sample Type]="COND (1-4 samples)","2.5",
    IF([Sample Type]="COND (Acid/Alkali/WFI set)","4",
      IF([Sample Type]="COND (EM)","4",
        IF([Sample Type]="LAL (ENDO)","3",
          IF([Sample Type]="LAL/ENDO (EM)","4",
            IF([Sample Type]="OSMO","2",
              IF([Sample Type]="PCR99","48",
                IF([Sample Type]="5068 rPA-HPLC (Protein A)","9",
                  IF([Sample Type]="pH (1-4 samples)","2.5",
                    IF([Sample Type]="pH (Acid/Alkali/WFI set)","4",
                      IF([Sample Type]="PNA23","4",
                        IF([Sample Type]="pNP (5080)","5",
                          IF([Sample Type]="SA23","12",
                            IF([Sample Type]="SKCS","24",
                              IF([Sample Type]="Titer (HPLC-Platform) Protein A","4",
                                IF([Sample Type]="TOC (EM)","4",
                                  IF([Sample Type]="TOC (Rinse: 1 sample)","2",
                                    IF([Sample Type]="TOC (Rinse: 2 samples)","3"))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Break it into multiple calculated field columns

Comment: Like Erin says.. No one is going to read this. Use a decent text editor to reformat your formula with line breaks and indentations, then indent 4 spaces so when you paste your formula here it is displayed as code

Comment: In SharePoint 2007 there was a [limit of 7 nested IF statements](https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/12/maximum-number-of-if-statements-in-a-calculated-column/), do not know if it was lifted in recent versions.. I would be surprised as other issues with the Calculated Column have never been fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenated or added IFs in groups of 7 (for 2007 and 2010) or 19 (for 2013 and later).

The trick for the IFs is to only nest 19 at a time and return either a text value or an empty string (""), and then concatenate another 19 nested IFs that return a text value or an empty string... repeat until done! If you are using 2007 or 2010, then nest 7 at a time, and then concatenate another 7.

```
if(State="AL","Alabama",
  if(State="AK","Alaska",
    if(State="AZ","Arizona",
      if(State="AR","Arkansas",
        if(State="CA","California",
          if(State="CO","Colorado",
            if(State="CT","Connecticut", "" ) ) ) ) ) ) ) &
if(State="DE","Delaware",
  if(State="FL","Florida",
    if(State="GA","Georgia",
      if(State="HI","Hawaii",
        if(State="ID","Idaho",
          if(State="IL","Illinois",
            if(State="IN","Indiana", "" ) ) ) ) ) ) ) &
etc...
```

For nested IFs that return a number, build the first 19 IFs to return a numeric value or a zero, and the add (+) another 19 IFs, until done.

```
    if(State="AL", 1,
      if(State="AK", 2,
        if(State="AZ", 3,
          if(State="AR", 4,
            if(State="CA", 5,
              if(State="CO", 6,
                if(State="CT", 7,  0  ) ) ) ) ) ) )   +
    if(State="DE", 8,
      if(State="FL", 9,
etc.
```

Here's an example that has 50 IFs (all 50 states): http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2018/03/a-sharepoint-calculated-column-for-all.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove one closing bracket from end `)`.